# How do I debug an upstart job?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init

I have the following job in `/etc/init/collector`:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

expect daemon

exec /usr/bin/twistd -y /path/to/my/tac/file
```

When I start the job with `sudo service collector start`, it hangs. If I `ctrl-c` and run `initctl list`, I see this:

```
collector start/killed, process 616
```

I can't see an instance of the `twistd` daemon in ps, and the HTTP server it's supposed to be providing does not exist.

I even tried this without 'expect daemon' and with a simple call to a one-line bash script using a `script` stanza, and it still doesn't work. I think I'm doing something very wrong. What could it be?

Comment: No answer, but I'm struggling with a similar issue. It might even be a bug in Upstart: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/438313 I don't know how to get from this hanging state other then rebooting. Also I believe it has to do with the `expect daemon` line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` of the entire shell using the `script` pragma (instead of `exec`) in conjunction with `exec >FILE 2>&1`, like so:

```
script
    exec >/path/to/some_log_file 2>&1
    exec your_command_here
end script
```

That should hopefully give you better insight into what's going on. I've found this useful for catching all sorts of problems in my upstart scripts. You *could* pipe your command's `stdout`/`stderr` directly, but you'll miss out on errors originating in the shell (like syntax errors).

On the other hand, if `service` is hanging, it *might* not even be hitting your script, in which case none of this will help, of course.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track. In the end I piped the output to `logger`, so that I could just tail `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Additionally, errors in the conf file itself are shown in `dmesg`. I found this out after I was not getting any output when using the above. I had made a typo in the chdir directive.

Comment: Where do you put that code?

Answer (score 2):

There's also the `console log` declarative, as defined here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console-log

I don't know enough about upstart to know if it's enabled by default, but you can enable it on a per upstart job basis, it'll by default output to `/var/log/upstart/<job>.log`

Answer (score 0):

Validate that upstart director exist , and add console log before the script phase.  (in upstart version upper then 1.4 it's the default)

console log

script
    exec >/path/to/some_log_file 2>&1
    exec your_command_here
end script

For more info check thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/207143/how-to-diagnose-upstart-errors/932155#932155